# Chatroom owners can star their own messages

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

I was able to star my own message by pinning it and unpinning it.  Pinning a message adds a star, even to your own messages, but when the pin is removed, the star remains.

Comment: As a chatroom owner you are awesome and you know it. status-bydesign I'd say.

Comment: "Pinning a message adds a star, even to your own messages, but when the pin is removed, the star remains." -- huh. I never noticed that.

Comment: Well, a pin kind of has to have an implied star, because a pin has a custom icon. If the pin isn't an implied star, then the first person who stars the pinned message will visually have no effect, because it doesn't add a number next to it for only having one star. There would be no visual difference between a pin with 0 stars and a pin with 1 star.

Comment: Dammit people - stop reporting bugs I *like*

Comment: Sorry :(  You can close this, I guess.

Comment: +1 @Bart for admitting that chat room owners are awesome :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you can. But have no fear, [Jeff said it was okay](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=222615#222615).

As such, this is currently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) – although at the time [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) seemed willing to entertain reasons why the behaviour should be changed, if you have a compelling reason.

Comment: Interesting.  Let's close it then!

Comment: Well, see, I wrote this crappy leaderboard that I can now game by starring my own messages: http://starleaderboard.azurewebsites.net/Room/Index/7

Comment: Not that that's a good reason...

Comment: Heh, that's pretty nifty